# How can I make the player start talking depending on if there is a text on the screen?

Tags: unity, c#

Before the game start, all my UI texts are **disabled**. They are all `TextMeshPro` types.

[image: Not active images]

When I'm running the game, in one of my scripts I'm activating only the Scene Image that also activating his child Scene Text.

Then a text is shown in the game for 10 seconds and the player is talking with a script.
I'm checking if one of the texts is not empty and if it is enabled:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BlendShapesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI[] texts;
    public bool startTalking = false;
    public float talkTime;
    public float duration;
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public float valueRange;
    private SkinnedMeshRenderer bodySkinnedMeshRenderer;
    private bool isTalking = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bodySkinnedMeshRenderer = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        StartTalking();

        if (startTalking && isTalking)
        {
            StartCoroutine(AnimateMouth());
            StartCoroutine(TalkTime());

            isTalking = false;
        }

        if (startTalking == false && isTalking == false)
        {
            isTalking = true;
        }
    }

    //Lerp between startValue and endValue over 'duration' seconds
    private IEnumerator LerpShape(float startValue, float endValue, float duration)
    {
        float elapsed = 0;
        while (elapsed < duration)
        {
            elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            float value = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, elapsed / duration);
            bodySkinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight(0, value);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    //animate open and closed, then repeat
    public IEnumerator AnimateMouth()
    {
        while (startTalking == true)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(0, valueRange, duration));
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(valueRange, 0, duration));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator TalkTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(talkTime);

        startTalking = false;
    }

    public void StartTalking()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (texts[i].text != "" && texts[i].transform.parent.gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true)
            {
                startTalking = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then after 10 seconds, I'm disabling the SceneImage in another script and the SceneText is also disabled.

So now both the Image and the Text are not active like before running the game.
But for some reason it keeps getting inside in the StartTalking method and set the flag to true:

```
public void StartTalking()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (texts[i].text != "" && texts[i].transform.parent.gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true)
            {
                startTalking = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the script where I'm setting the Scene Image to be active or not active :
The variable name is uiSceneImage :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using SpeedTutorMainMenuSystem;
using System.IO;

public class PlayingInGameScenesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CinemachineFreeLook[] freeLookCams;
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera[] virtualCams;
    public LockController lockController;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject uiSceneImage;
    public float transitionSpeed = 5f;
    public float thresHold = 0.1f;
    public bool talkingProcess = true;
    public SaveLoad saveLoad;
    public bool newGameHasLoaded = false;

    private bool newGame = true;
    private bool loaded = false;

    private void Start()
    {
      
    }
    public void PlayingSceneInGame()
    {
        PlayingSceneStatesControls(true);
        StartCoroutine(ScenePlayingTime());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != "Main Menu" && newGame == true && MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame == false)
        {
            PlayingSceneInGame();
            newGame = false;
        }

        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != "Main Menu" && MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame == true && loaded == false)
        {
            newGameHasLoaded = true;
            loaded = true;
        }
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
       
    }

    private void PlayingSceneStatesControls(bool LockState)
    {
        lockController.LockControl(LockState);

        if (LockState == true)
        {
            uiSceneImage.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            talkingProcess = false;
            uiSceneImage.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ScenePlayingTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);

        PlayingSceneStatesControls(false);

        freeLookCams[0].enabled = false;
        freeLookCams[1].enabled = true;

        var brain = Camera.main.GetComponent<CinemachineBrain>().m_DefaultBlend.m_Time;

        StartCoroutine(saveLoad.SaveWithTime());
    }
}
```

All the texts are deactivated. One of them is not empty but they are all deactivated and it's still getting inside and set the startTalking flag to true.

The texts are `TextMeshProUGUI` types so I wonder why it's setting the flag to true if they are disabled ?

I used a break point in the StartTalking method and I see that the activeInHierarchy flag is false but it's still setting the flag to true.

I'm also not sure about the rest of the script code if I didn't mess all the other flags.

My script was written in another way before. The StartTalking method didn't exist and I used a reference to this script from other scripts to enable `startTalking` by setting it to true (this worked fine). But I thought 'maybe I can do it all in this script without a reference to it' in order to decide when the player should talk and when not.One script to control all the player talkings. My logic is that when there is a text on the screen from these 3 UI texts, the player can talk.

Comment: @DMGregory Right, Then how can I check if the text parent object is disabled or enabled ? Because I'm disabling the Image of the text but the text it self is still active then I need to check somehow for the Image if it's disable or not.  So instead this texts[i].enabled == true how can I check for the Image or the parent of the texts[i] if it's disabled or enabled ?

Comment: You mean whether the parent is Active, not Enabled. Behaviours can be enabled/disabled, but Behaviours do not have children. So there is no such thing as a disabled parent. There is such a thing as an inactive parent, since GameObjects can have children and be set Active or inactive. [Did you read the documentation to learn how to check for this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html)?

Comment: Wouldn't be an easy solution to just remove the text before you disable the element? Setting text + enabling for displaying and deleting + disabling for hiding. That way you can be as well sure that not some wrong text is getting displayed if by mistake the text field gets enabled and has still some old text in it.